# Чье удобство?

Tags: грамотная-речь

"Также помните об удобстве (для) посетителей". Нутром чую, нельзя так сказать. Но как иначе? Если "...об удобстве посетителей", то выходит, что это посетители должны быть удобными))))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Удобство - это наличие условий, возможностей для лёгкого, приятного, необременительного пользования **чем**-либо, или удовлетворения каких-либо нужд, потребностей.

Так как посетители лицо одушевлённое, то **удобность** посетителей для персонала и удобство самих посетителей - не омонимичны.

Теперь по поводу "для". Удобство для посетителей - это туалет. "Удобство для" - это приспособление, оборудование, делающее что-либо удобным, благоустроенным.

Если вы действительно заботитесь об удобстве посетителей, то помимо удобств для посетителей (пандус, лифт, таблички), будет ещё вежливый и тактичный персонал.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы вообще это слово заменила, т.к. удобствами называют и туалетные комнаты. Получается некая двусмысленность. Лучше уж "помните о комфорте посетителей". "Для", мне кажется, лишнее.

Answer (score 0):

А мне все же думается, что "удобство для посетителеей" - это нормально

Answer (score 0):

А можно контекст? Фраза сама по себе, в т.ч. и все предложенные варианты трактовки, отдаёт какой-то фантасмагоричностью.
Это посетителям предлагается подумать о собственном удобстве / удобстве для себя? Тогда это день открытых дверей в дурдоме.
Обслуживающему персоналу? Так ему не помнить надо, а создавать. И не удобства, а, скажем, комфорт. И как правило - клиентам, не посетителям (если это не театр, не закусочная, не поликлиника, и не что-то подобное).
Ну а если это кто-то из звена, напрямую с обслуживанием клиентов не сталкивающемуся (уборщица, кассир, диктор на вокзале, водитель/машинист,...), то вменение им в обязанности чего-то такого оговаривается конкретно. 
Не допускайте очередей, убедитесь, что пассажиры заняли свои места и пристегнули ремни, будьте приветливы и опрятны...

Comment: Удобств**о** - это синоним комфорта, но только в единственном числе. Удобств**а** имеют уже другое значение.

Помнить об удобстве значит, что при выполнении своих прямых обязанностей подумать не помешают ли твои действия посетителям. Например, уборщица обязана мыть полы, но не стоит вытирать под столом, за которым сидят клиенты. Все подобные случаи прописать проблематично, поэтому и дают общий принцип для выбора решений в спорной ситуации.

Comment: >>Удобство - это синоним комфорта, но только в единственном числе.
Спорно. Но я и не говорил о синониме, а подыскивал более тосно значение..

Comment: Дальнейшее у меня рассказывает о возможном контексте фразы. Уборщица из примера выше разве о комфорте посетителей забыла? Скорей уж тогда о комфортности пребывания, но зачем городить такой эвфемизм при наличии слова удобство не знаю.

А все определения проверены по различным словарям в том числе и словарям синонимов.

Comment: >Дальнейшее у меня рассказывает    

Я  читал.