# "Удобство" и "комфорт": синонимы или нет?

Tags: грамотная-речь, плеоназм

Вчера писала текст и хотела употребить там рядом два слова: "удобство и комфорт". А потом задумалась, а не будет ли это плеоназмом? Или же все-таки эти понятия различаются по смыслу? Как вы думаете?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Удобство и комфорт - клише, ставящее рядом разные значения этих слов:

Комфорт в Энциклопедическом словаре:
Комфорт - (англ. comfort) - бытовые удобства; благоустроенность и уют жилищ,общественных учреждений, средств сообщения и т. п.-то же, что удобство.

В переносном смысле:душевный комфорт - состояние внутреннего спокойствия, отсутствие разлада с собой и окружающим миром.

"Удобство и комфорт" означает"бытовые удобства и душевный комфорт". Если Вы хотите сказать именно это, вполне допустимо использование этого клише.

Answer (score 1):

Да, это синонимы. У слова *удобство* значение шире, но как правило,  их вполне можно заменить друг на друга. Подробнее о значении слова "удобство" можно прочитать в этом [вопросе](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/18488/%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%8C-%D1%87%D1%8C%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE) В любом случае определить есть ли избыточность или нет, не имея самого текста перед глазами невозможно.

Answer (score 0):

Лично я бы не назвал это синонимами. Комфорт это слово заимствованное и в русском языке, как правило, оно замещает такие слова как - удобство, уют, покой и др.

Мне так думается, употребление его хоть как-то оправдано только в отношении бытовых условий, когда не знаешь, какое слово подобрать :)